# Count the number of entries for a given column

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

Its probably an easy question but hard for me: I have the following table (columns)

```
 [id, email_from, email_to, email_subject, timestamp]
```

id and timestamp are numeric and the rest are text fields

for that example:

```
  [1, john@mail.com, patrick@mail.com, ...]
  [2, john@mail.com, carol@mail.com, ...]
  [3, john@mail.com, john@mail.com, ...]
  [4, john@mail.com, jimmy@mail.com, ...]
  [5, jimmy@mail.com, carol@mail.com, ...]
  [6, jimmy@mail.com, john@mail.com, ...]
  [8, jimmy@mail.com, carol@mail.com, ...]
  [9, carol@mail.com, patrick@mail.com, ...]
```

I'd like to retrieve the number of mails sent by each user. The result should be like:

```
[john@mail.com,4]
[jimmy@mail.com,3]
[carol@mail.com,1]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
select email_from, count(*) from yourtable group by email_from
```

and possibly adding an

order by count(*) desc

if you want it ordered by most to least emails sent

Answer (score 0):

SELECT
    email_from,
    COUNT(email_from) AS 'Count'
FROM
    table_name
GROUP BY
    email_from